# Dump Assembly of given c++ line(s)

Tags: c++, linux, assembly, disassembly

Say I have code like this (notice that in the editor I can see line numbers)

```
//File example_optimization.cpp

#1 int spreadi = (d_ai - d_bi);
#2 int transactionCosti = spreadi / (spreadi < 10 ? 1 : 10);
```

If the compiler is an optimizing compiler and the correct flags are set, I want to prove to myself that the division by 1 is not actually taking place.

Is there a tool in linux (or a combination of tools that can be used through a pipe) where I can say something like:

```
ctoassembler -c g++ -l 1 2 example_optimization.cpp
```

So this command says, call ctoassembler use compiler and linker gnu g++, and dump lines 1 through 2 of c++ file example_optimization.cpp. The default is to output the assembler code to stdout.

I don't really care what the usage is. I am interested in being able to see what my code is turned into by a compiler without having to search for it myself.

I don't mind using object files if that makes it easier, but somehow it is preferable to display the c++ source code and the corresponding assembler code "side-by-side".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GCC will will stop with the produced assembler files:

> -S Stop after the stage of compilation proper; do not assemble. The output is in the form of an assembler code file for each non-assembler
>   input file specified. By default, the assembler file name for a source
>   file is made by replacing the suffix ‘.c’, ‘.i’, etc., with ‘.s’.
>
> Input files that don't require compilation are ignored.

Source: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Overall-Options.html#Overall-Options

Your other option is just to debug the program and have a look at the assembler.

Answer (score 1):

Run the code through gdb, putting a break point at the line of C you want, run, then type `disassemble` to view the next few lines of code.